# Preview/Print MS Access Report from Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, reporting

I have an Visual Basic 2013 program which connects to a MS Access 2010 database. After the program calculates and writes values out to the DB, I need to print a report that is in the Access DB.

I have read through this:  [How To Automate Microsoft Access From Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317113)

I found similar questions such as this: [Vb.Net preview report from access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086304/vb-net-preview-report-from-access-database) but they do not use the DoCmd.OpenReport method.

The code I have now is as follows:

```
Imports Access = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access

Public Class FrmReports

    Dim oAccess As Access.application

    Private Sub btnSumByPlan_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSumByPlan.Click

        oAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
        oAccess.visible = True
        oAccess.opencurrentdatabase ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=|DataDirectory|\CLI_CRVM.accdb")

        oAccess.docmd.openreport(ReportName:="SumByPlan", View:=Access.AcView.acViewPreview)

    End Sub
End Class
```

This code compiles but gives me the following error when it runs:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in CLI CRVM.exe
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.ApplicationClass' to class ype   'CLI_CRVM.Access.applicationclass'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had to add stubs to get it to compile and then got this when I ran it:  "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in CLI CRVM.exe"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to the `OpenCurrentDatabase()` method of an `Access.Application` object is just the location of the database file, not an OLEDB connection string. Your statement should be something more like

```vb
oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase("C:\path\to\CLI_CRVM.accdb")
```

Also, I am unable to say for certain if `|DataDirectory|` is meaningful in that context, but I highly doubt it.

Comment: You are correct - `|DataDirectory|` is not recognized here.  Is there another reference I can use as I do not know where this will be installed?